# how to get a react icon to randomly move around a page (using react and tailwind)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

i am trying to move the octopus icon randomly around the page where the octopus eye will be pointing towards the mouse cursor.

i googled it, but using tailwind css, i could not find any solution. Starting point of the div doesn't matter, nor does the ending point. It just needs to randomly move around the page for the duration a user is on that page.

Comment: please add code to your quesion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mousemove` event to achieve this

recently I created a clock in which I used this code to rotate the clock towards the mouse

here is the link of live [example](https://the-clock-one.vercel.app/)

```
useEffect(() => {
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)

const onMouseMove = (event: any) => {
const card: HTMLDivElement | any = document.getElementById('clock')
var ax = -(window.innerWidth / 2 - event?.pageX) / 20;
var ay = (window.innerHeight / 2 - event?.pageY) / 10;
ax = ax / 1.7;
ay = ay / 1.7;

card.setAttribute("style", `transform: rotateY(${ax}deg) 
rotateX(${ay}deg);-webkit-transform: rotateY(${ax}deg) 
 rotateX(${ay}deg);-moz-transform: rotateY(${ax}deg) 
 rotateX(${ax}deg)`);
  };
```